# Visual Studio 2019 Formatting Json behavior

Tags: json, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 to maintain a .json file.  The default auto formatting will cause my JSON to look like this:

```
[
  {
    "episode": "01x01",
    "title": "Ambush",
    "quote": "Great leaders inspire greatness in others."
  },
  {
    "episode": "01x02",
    "title": "Rising Malevolence",
    "quote": "Belief is not a matter of choice, but of conviction."
  },
  {
    "episode": "01x03",
    "title": "Shadow of Malevolence",
    "quote": "Easy is the path to wisdom for those not blinded by ego."
  }
]
```

If I enter my JSON like this, I would like to retain the expanded formatting alongside other objects I have chosen to condense into one line.

```
[
  { 
    "episode": "01x01", 
    "title": "Ambush", 
    "quote": "Great leaders inspire greatness in others."
   },
  { "episode": "01x02", "title": "Rising Malevolence", "quote": "Belief is not a matter of choice, but of conviction." },
  { "episode": "01x03", "title": "Shadow of Malevolence", "quote": "Easy is the path to wisdom for those not blinded by ego." }
]
```

I've turned off "Automatic formatting" and "Format on paste" but this neglects to fix indentation, causing me to manually indent.

Does anyone know if it's possible to have the formatter behave as I have specified?

[image]